# Tensorflow DNNRegressor didn't learn well

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, non-linear-regression

I want to use DNNRegressor in TensorFlow to fit a simple quadratic function. But the result is not good. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def extract_prediction(l):
    ll = list(l)
    predict = []
    n = 0
    for i in ll:

        predict.append(i['predictions'][0])
        n += 1

    return predict


x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 500).reshape([-1, 1])
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, x.shape)
y = np.square(x) + noise
print(y.shape)
feature = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x')
print(np.min(y), ' ', np.max(y))
est = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(hidden_units=[30],
                                feature_columns=[feature],
                                activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh,

optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.3))
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'x': x}, y=y, 
                                              shuffle=False)
p_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'x': x} , y=y, 
                                                shuffle=False)
est.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=50000)
predict = est.evaluate(input_fn=p_input_fn)
print(predict)
predict = est.predict(input_fn=p_input_fn)
p = extract_prediction(predict)

plt.plot(y, 'b')
plt.plot(p, 'r')
plt.show()
```

And the result figure is here:

[image]

What should I do to improve the performance? Actually, it works well if I use tf.Variable to define weights and bias and write out the network by myself. But why estimator doesn't work for me?

For the shuffle, I have tried but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Hard to say. I'd try changing the batch size, shuffling the batches, using the default optimizer and activation function, adding more hidden layers, and setting the `dropout` argument in the estimator's constructor.

Comment: Are you familiar with Cross Validated?  stats.stackexchange.com